# Double-clicking from Ribbon to load a TaskPane breaks functionality, which prevents TaskPane from showing next time

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, office-addins

I have created a simple JavaScript Excel add-in using the [Yeoman generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-angular).
When I double-click on the Ribbon button to show the add-in's pane, two panes show up. One of the panes may not work. After closing the panes, I can not show the TaskPane again. Only reloading the web page allows fixing the issue.

[image: Ribbon double-click] [image: After switching between simultaneously open panels.]

The console may contain this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at
'https://euc-excel.officeapps.live.com/x/AppSettingsHandler.ashx?app=Excel'
from origin 'https://adxteam-my.sharepoint.com' has been blocked by
CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
requested resource. excel-boot.min.js:3 GET
https://euc-excel.officeapps.live.com/x/AppSettingsHandler.ashx?app=Excel
net::ERR_FAILED
```

The issue appears in the online Excel version only.

I believe that many users have a bad habit of double-clicking buttons. Therefore, this problem can be a nuisance.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>05c2e1c9-3e1d-406e-9a91-e9ac64854143</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Contoso Task Pane Add-in"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="A template to get started."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Workbook"/>
  </Hosts>  
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <GetStarted>
            <Title resid="GetStarted.Title"/>
            <Description resid="GetStarted.Description"/>
            <LearnMoreUrl resid="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
          </GetStarted>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url" />
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
              <Group id="CommandsGroup">
                <Label resid="CommandsGroup.Label" />
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                </Icon>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="TaskpaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812" />
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html" />
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Get started with your sample add-in!" />
        <bt:String id="CommandsGroup.Label" DefaultValue="Commands Group" />
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane" />
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="Your sample add-in loaded succesfully. Go to the HOME tab and click the 'Show Taskpane' button to get started." />
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane" />
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: it would be great if you could share the manifest, therefore i could have a local repro on this issue.

Comment: updated with a manifest.

Comment: i just have a try on Excel online as well as the Win32, but i got an error message, manifest is invalid. can you sideload the manifest in your side?

Comment: Please use this manifest for a server add-in.
https://online-addins.ablebits.com/testdoubleclick/manifestServer.xml

Comment: I have tried to validate on Windows and Excel online, but both 2 platforms are not able to repro this issue. what's your Excel version?

Comment: My current Excel online version is 16.0.12725.35053
Please see the following video that demonstrates the problem:
http://youtu.be/s_6_k1KE6Oc?hd=1

Comment: I can repro now, a bug 4052244 was created, team will be on investigation for this issue